# tsql select with all variations of joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

For an export I have to select all stats for all years and groups, even if the combination has no amount to export.

Here an example and expected result:

```
DECLARE @years TABLE (yr INT)
INSERT @years VALUES (2020),(2021),(2022)

DECLARE @grps TABLE (grp INT)
INSERT @grps VALUES (1),(2),(3)

DECLARE @stats TABLE (item INT, yr INT, grp INT, amount INT)
INSERT @stats VALUES
 (1,2021,1,344)
,(1,2021,2,34)
,(1,2021,3,44)
,(1,2020,1,249)
,(1,2020,3,70)
,(2,2021,1,850)
,(2,2021,2,1260)
,(2,2020,1,799)


/* EXPECTED RESULT */
/*
|item|year|grp |amout|
|1   |2020|1   | 249 |
|1   |2020|2   |   0 |
|1   |2020|3   |  70 |
|1   |2021|1   | 344 |
|1   |2021|2   |  34 |
|1   |2021|3   |  44 |
|1   |2022|1   |   0 |
|1   |2022|2   |   0 |
|1   |2022|3   |   0 |
|2   |2020|1   | 799 |
|2   |2020|2   |   0 |
|2   |2020|3   |   0 |
|2   |2021|1   | 850 |
|2   |2021|2   |1260 |
|2   |2021|3   |   0 |
|2   |2022|1   |   0 |
|2   |2022|2   |   0 |
|2   |2022|3   |   0 |
*/
```

I get id done with this query:

```
SELECT item.item
,yr.yr
,grp.grp
,ISNULL(st.amount,0) [amount]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item FROM @stats) item
CROSS APPLY (SELECT yr FROM @years) yr
CROSS APPLY (SELECT grp FROM @grps) grp
LEFT JOIN @stats st
ON st.item = item.item
AND st.yr = yr.yr
AND st.grp = grp.grp
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Is there no simpler solution to this?

Comment: No, that is the method, `CROSS JOIN` the values you need and then `LEFT JOIN` to the dataset you want to aggregate/summarise. Though in a real environment, you would likely also have a table for your items, and so no need for a `SELECT DISTINCT item` against your table `@stats`.

Comment: Your clauses `CROSS APPLY`s (for example `CROSS APPLY (SELECT yr FROM @years) yr`) could also be abbreviated to `CROSS JOIN`s: `CROSS JOIN @years yr`.

Answer (score 0):

It's debatable if it's a simpler solution.
But you can cross join in a CTE to get all expected combos.
Then left join the CTE to the existing data.

> ```
> DECLARE @years TABLE (yr INT);
> INSERT @years VALUES (2020),(2021),(2022);
>
> DECLARE @grps TABLE (grp INT);
> INSERT @grps VALUES (1),(2),(3);
>
> DECLARE @stats TABLE (item INT, yr INT, grp INT, amount INT)
> INSERT @stats VALUES
>  (1,2021,1,344)
> ,(1,2021,2,34)
> ,(1,2021,3,44)
> ,(1,2020,1,249)
> ,(1,2020,3,70)
> ,(2,2021,1,850)
> ,(2,2021,2,1260)
> ,(2,2020,1,799);
>
> ;WITH CTE_YEARS AS (
>   SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM @years
> )
> , CTE_GROUPS AS (
>   SELECT DISTINCT grp FROM @grps
> )
> , CTE_ITEMS AS (
>   SELECT DISTINCT item FROM @stats
> )
> , CTE_ALL_YEAR_GROUP_ITEMS AS (
>   SELECT y.yr, g.grp, i.item
>   FROM CTE_YEARS y
>   CROSS JOIN CTE_GROUPS g
>   CROSS JOIN CTE_ITEMS i
> )
> SELECT 
>   cte.item
> , cte.yr
> , cte.grp
> , ISNULL(stat.amount, 0) AS amount
> FROM CTE_ALL_YEAR_GROUP_ITEMS cte
> LEFT JOIN @stats stat
>   ON stat.item = cte.item
>  AND stat.yr = cte.yr
>  AND stat.grp = cte.grp
> ORDER BY 1,2,3
> ```

> | item | yr | grp | amount |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2020 | 1 | 249 |
> | 1 | 2020 | 2 | 0 |
> | 1 | 2020 | 3 | 70 |
> | 1 | 2021 | 1 | 344 |
> | 1 | 2021 | 2 | 34 |
> | 1 | 2021 | 3 | 44 |
> | 1 | 2022 | 1 | 0 |
> | 1 | 2022 | 2 | 0 |
> | 1 | 2022 | 3 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2020 | 1 | 799 |
> | 2 | 2020 | 2 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2020 | 3 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2021 | 1 | 850 |
> | 2 | 2021 | 2 | 1260 |
> | 2 | 2021 | 3 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2022 | 1 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2022 | 2 | 0 |
> | 2 | 2022 | 3 | 0 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=738526c728bb29d1a779d517e6143c27)*